# New ASP.Net project but asking to sign in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis-express

I created a new ASP.net core project using VS2019. I did not modify anything from the automatically created weatherforecast controller. My problem is, everytime I just try to debug, the browser pops up asking me to sign in. Is there a default user and password created? How to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably you are using `Windows Authentication` while create your `Asp.NET` project, try `uncheck` Authentication it will allow getting into the landing page of your application

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that during the creation of the project you didn't add authentication. There's an option to add authentication by default.